# How to mark data sent with tcp?

Tags: json, http, tcp, format

I'm quite confused about how I should mark the data I am sending with tcp. For example in a http request I would send json, but what about tcp?

Comment: You can use whatever your want if you are writing both sides. If you are sending to another application, find out what that application expects.

Comment: I'm writing a tcp server and tcp client, how can the server know if i send for example "John" that the name is John? @johnelemans

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. TCP is just a byte stream with no inherent semantics. It is like writing some numbers on a paper and giving it to somebody else - they don't have any meaning by themselves. Only if both parties agree how the data should be interpreted (like it being an encoded image, a password, ...) they get a meaning. So the logic is in the client and server, not the data. This is the same with JSON too - it's just bytes. Only if client and server agree that this should be interpreted as structured JSON they will treat it like that.